# Laravel 5 URL::asset() not being rendered in view

Tags: php, url, path, laravel-5

In my app.blade.php (master template) I have a section called `@yield('scripts')` located near the bottom of the page as follows:

```
    <html>
    <header>...</header>
    <body>

       ....
       <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
       <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/site.js')}}"></script>
       @yield('scripts')
   </body>
   </html>
```

I have view called index.blade.php which references the above section in order to add some scripts that are only used in that view as follows:

```
  @section('scripts')

   <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/pikaday.js') }}"></script>

  @endsection
```

However I've noticed the path for the first script that is declared `js/moment.js` isn't being rendered correctly when I view the source. For some strange reason its being rendered as follows in my view:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js')); ?>">
<script src="http://localhost:8000/js/pikaday.js">
```

I know the script is in the right location and when I add a new script to the declaration above it, it seems to get rendered fine but the first script is always being incorrectly rendered. When I declare as follows:

```
  @section('scripts')

    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/pikaday.js') }}"></script>

  @endsection
```

I get the following output:

```
 <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/moment.js')); ?>">
 <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/moment.js">
 <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/pikaday.js">
```

Any one know what going on here?

Comment: This is probably caused by a mistake somewhere before this code in the view. Please edit your question and add the full view code

Comment: You were right. I had commented out a blade form input using {{-- --}} tags but the form input was formed incorrectly. I assumed the comment tags would ignore the badly formed input field - clearly not.